# documentation of function calls

Tags: php, documentation

How to have the function calls documented in php ? I would like to have something like :

= = = =

***function_name1(list of args)***

**description of the function**

foo bar (extracted from php-doc like comments)

**calls:**

function_name2(list of args)

function_name3(list of args)

**is called in** 
  function4
  function5

= = = = = = = = = = = =

***function_name2(list of args)***

**description of the function**

foo bar (extracted from php-doc like comments)

**calls:**

function_name5(list of args)

**is called in**

function1

..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859791/php-cleanup-the-junk   "Is there a utility that can trace the PHP code from the main index.php so that I can figure out what isn't being used and what is, or am I stuck doing a manual cleanup?"

Comment: I've actually forgotten this question and ask a similar (but different) one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861107/reverse-engineer-phphtml-files-not-object-oriented-ones-to-produce-a-diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most widely used [documentation standard in the PHP world is PHPDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc). It is derived from JavaDoc. A large number of IDEs support [PHPDoc](http://www.phpdoc.de/), which means they can automate documentation and you can gain code completion and other features from it.

Several tools exist to autogenerate documentation from PHPDoc code annotations. PHPdocumentor already mentioned elsewhere is the most prominent, but you can also use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual) which allows for a wider range of documentation formats

**Update:** phpDocumentor is quite outdated and cannot properly work with PHP5.3 code (tried closures?). There is (currently) two worthwhile alternatives to look at: [DocBlox](http://www.docblox-project.org) and [phpDox](https://github.com/theseer/phpdox).

Comment: thanks !- doxygen is very usefull, has a clear great format (however, it doesn't document calls from function located in an included file for PHP).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [PhpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/DOM/default