# PHP - Cleanup the Junk

Tags: php

I have inherited a very messy project.  There are at least 3 versions that I can tell in it.

Is there a utility that can trace the PHP code from the main index.php so that I can figure out what isn't being used and what is, or am I stuck doing a manual cleanup?

Thanks

****Update****

I don't think I've been clear about what I'm looking for, that or I'm not understanding how the products mentioned work.  What I'm looking for is something that can run on a folder (directory) and step through the project and give me a report of which files are actually referenced or used (in the case of images, CSS, etc).

This project has several thousand files and it's a very small project.  I'm trying to clean it up and when I do a "search in files" in my IDE I get 3 or 4 references and can't easily tell which one is the right one.

Hope that makes it a little clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross referencing software really lets you explore which functions are used for what.

**[PHPXref](http://phpxref.sourceforge.net/)** is quite good..

For example Yoast used it to **[cross reference the Wordpress PHP code](http://xref.yoast.com/)**. Take a look at the Wordpress example of how powerful it is.

For example, start by browsing **[the WP trunk](http://xref.yoast.com/trunk/nav.html?index.html)**. Click on some of the file names on the left and observe how the required files are listed, along with defined classes and methods, etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are several utilities that can do this, what first comes mind is Zend Studio's built in Optimizer that will run through your files and issue notices on a per file basis, including unused variables, warnings, etc. Alternatively, you can run your program in E_STRICT and PHP will notify you of some of your issues.

Answer (score 1):

Be very careful of such cleanup tools, especially in PHP or Javascript. They work reasonably well in languages like Java, but any language that allows `Eval()` can trip an automated tool up, sometimes in devilishly clever ways, depending on how clever the original code developer thought they were.

Answer (score 1):

You need the inclued extension. You can generate include graphs using GraphViz, see below for example code.

There are some useful examples on PHP.net: http://www.php.net/manual/en/inclued.examples-implementation.php

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [xdebug's code coverage](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/code_coverage), possibly as an auto_append. However, itś rather limited and it would require you to have either 100% test-cases (which I doubt as you say the project is a mess), or the tenacity to go through every possible action on the site, and even then you'll have to apply good judgement whether you can remove a portion of code because it isn't used, or leave it there because a certain condition just hasn't been met yet in your cases. On a side note: stepping through the code with xdebug's remote debugger has really helped me in the past to quickly get the different mechanisms & flows in unknown projects.

Answer (score 0):

I would try opening the whole project in [NetBeans PHP](http://netbeans.org/), its a great tool which we use for huge projects. You can easily see warnings and notifications and also follow usage of functions/classes easily. Try it!
I would recommend against automatic cleanups and the likes. Even if the code seems to work afterwards, I wouldnt sleep very well at night...